# Generic types in Scala

Tags: scala, templates, generics, functional-programming, scala-collections

I want to overloading constructor of abstract class with specific type. For example, I have:

```
abstract class Polinom(v: T)
```

So, when I create `Polinom[String]`, I want to call `constructor(String)`, for Int I want to call `constructor(Int)`. If `T != String and T != Int` then I call `constructor(T)`. In addition, for `T == Int` my object must have method `add`, for `T == String` - `reverse`, for `T != String and T != Int` object doesn't has this methods. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use evidence parameters for this:

```
class Polinom[T](v: T) {

  def add(i: Int)(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = v + i
  def reverse(implicit ev: T <:< String): String = ev(v).reverse

}

val x = new Polinom(50)
val y = new Polinom("hello")
val z = new Polinom(None)

println(x.add(3))
println(y.reverse)
//println(z.add(3)) <- Isn't allowed. Error: Cannot prove that None.type <:< Int
```

If you want specific constructors for `Int` and `String` and can't get enough of that implicit evidence, you can do this:

```
def this(i: Int)(implicit ev: Int =:= T) = this({
    //do special int stuff here
    println("I am in the special int constructor")
    ev(i)
  })

  def this(s: String)(implicit ev: String =:= T) = this({
    //do special string stuff here
    println("I am in the special string constructor")
    ev(s)
  })
```

EDIT: Apparently, the above didn't work for the OP, although it seems to be working for me, but you can always make a companion object and overload the apply method, as the other answers suggested.

```
class Polinom[T] private(v: T)
object Polinom {
  def apply(i: Int): Polinom[Int] = new Polinom(i)
  def apply(s: String): Polinom[String] = new Polinom(s)
  def apply[T](x: T): Polinom[T] = new Polinom(x)
}

val x = Polinom(50)
val y = Polinom("hello")
val z = Polinom(None)

println(x.add(3))
println(y.reverse)
//println(z.add(3)) <- Isn't allowed. Error: Cannot prove that None.type <:< Int
```

[Link to Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/j8fWjvVFS3CumCo3WbUgqQ) (the demo's below)

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/j8fWjvVFS3CumCo3WbUgqQ.js"></script>
```

Comment: It tourn out that `A <:< B` is the same as `B => A` thus it is just a function from **B** to **A**, which if it is implicit, then the compile treat it as an implicit conversion, which obviously you can always call explicitly. More info here: https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `A => B`, not `B => A`.

Comment: But what about constructors?

Comment: @archi1998 See the updated answer. I've included secondary constructors

Comment: Error:(20, 13) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both constructor Polinom in class Polinom of type (i: Int)(implicit ev: Int =:= T)Polinom[T]
and  constructor Polinom in class Polinom of type (v: T)Polinom[T]
match argument types (Int)
    val x = new Polinom(50) @user

Comment: @archi1998 It seems to be working for me in Scastie, but you can always use companion objects, like Luis suggested

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to model that as an **ADT**, something like:

```
sealed trait Polinom[T] {
  def v: T
}

object Polinom {
  final case class IntPolinom private[Polinom] (v: Int) extends Polinom[Int] {
    def add(x: Int): IntPolinom =
      this.copy(v = this.v + x)
  }

  final case class StrPolinom private[Polinom] (v: String) extends Polinom[String] {
    def reverse: StrPolinom =
      this.copy(v = this.v.reverse)
  }

  final case class GenericPolinom[T] private[Polinom] (v: T) extends Polinom[T]

  def apply[T](v: Int): IntPolinom =
    IntPolinom(v)

  def apply[T](v: String): StrPolinom =
    StrPolinom(v)

  def apply[T](v: T): GenericPolinom[T] =
    GenericPolinom(v)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Polinom[T](v: T)

object Polinom {
  def apply(i: Int): Polinom[Int] = constructor(i)
  def apply(s: String): Polinom[String] = constructor(s)
  def apply[T](v: T): Polinom[T] = constructor(v)
}

Polinom(0)
Polinom("hello")
Polinom(None)
```

For examples of the `add` and `reverse` methods, see the other answers to this question.

Comment: @user One question at a time ;)